# Spring ldap integration

Tags: spring, spring-ldap

I am new to spring security and LDAP too.
Trying to integrate ldap server using spring security 
Also followed a couple of examples or the same.

Security xml looks like this

```
<beans:beans xmlns:="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" >              
        <intercept-url pattern="/jsp/login.htm" />               
        <intercept-url pattern="/jsp/home*" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/jsp/search*"  />
        <intercept-url pattern="/jsp/errorSearch*"/>
        <form-login login-page="/jsp/login.htm" default-target-url="/jsp/home.htm" login-processing-url="/jsp/j_spring_security_check"/>            
        <logout logout-url="/jsp/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/jsp/login.htm" />
    </http>


    <ldap-server 
        url="ldap://honts0102.homeoffice.test.com/DC=homeoffice,DC=com" 
        manager-dn="CN=gec-jirasvc,OU=GEC_Service Accounts,OU=Users,OU=GEC,DC=homeoffice,DC=com" 
        manager-password="userpasswd"/>
    <authentication-manager>
        <ldap-authentication-provider `enter code here`
        user-search-filter="(sAMAccountName={0})"
           user-search-base="OU=GEC_Service Accounts,OU=Users,OU=GEC,DC=homeoffice,DC=com">
        </ldap-authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


</beans:beans>
```

The manager dn I used here is a service account.
Not getting any error at the back end but the login page is not authenticating the users.
I would really appreciate if anyone could help me resolving this and provide me some way by which I can at-least check/set logs for LDAP server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same "error" and i have resolved it with this simple configuration:

```
<bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg value="homeoffice.com" />
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://honts0102.homeoffice.test.com:389/" />
    <property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
    <property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
</bean>

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" />
</authentication-manager>

...
```

With the property:

```
property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true" />
```

Spring security will raise exceptions when the authentication with ldap server return errors. So you can see better where you have errors.

Comment: I tried doing this but still I don't get any debug log to check if I am getting connected to the LDAP server or is there any other issue.

Comment: How you test your login with ldap ? Have you checked if your jsp tags are correct ? You have a great document writted by Louis E.Mauget about Form Based Authentication. I think you can found a solution or way for found solution: http://fr.scribd.com/doc/34531398/Form-Based-Authentication

Comment: Thanks.The JSP tags for form based authentication are working properly the reason I am sure of that is I had created various users and roles in spring security and with those set of users I was able to login in the application.the problem starts when I try to use LDAP server.So right now the spring security xml looks like this

Comment: Okay, i have published an example on github of authentication through an ldap server with spring security. My example does not use roles. When you are not defined roles in spring security, your application is fully open. What interests us here is able to connect through LDAP. Normally, if your username / password are correct, the login page will redirect to the site root (/).
Check here: https://github.com/m-reka/spring-security-ldap

Comment: I implemented the LDAP authentication following the example.Now I want to integrate the DB authorization along with this I searched online but did not get any example with the LDAP provider we used can any one please guide me

Comment: You have two options. (1) Create groups in a database (which adds configuration and redundancy) as you say. (2) Or, create security groups in AD (Active Directory) mapped that with your user through an authorities mapper (No database, no more big services, no more big configuration). I will opt for the second most elegant solution. 

However, if you want to use the first solution you can follow the steps described in this great tutorial: http://bit.ly/137R7FS or follow this steps for second solution : http://bit.ly/10MXATC . 

Best regards, Mentor Reka.

Comment: I checked the first example but it shows both authentication and authorization using DB connection only.My use case is something like I want LDAP active directory implementation for authentication but for role authorization will be using the roles defined in DB .Please let me know if you have ever come across such example.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a question for you before that. Do you own groups in your active directory users already associate that you would like to authenticate? If yes (I think), why you absolutely want to have a redundant roles in your database? Simply map the roles / security group associated with the user (which authenticates) and simply implement the AuthoritiesMapper.

However, I have searched and found a solution in spring forum that exposes a similar problem: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?65975-ldap-and-Jdbc-in-Spring-Security

Comment: No as off now we don't want to rely on active directory groups.For this reason I want to load the roles from DB.Anyways thanks for your help I was able to do DB authorization using the UserDetailsContextMapperImpl class .I am curious to know when do we use the remember me feature and trying to implement concurrent session management now .

Comment: Good ! For use remember me feature, you can use your database and implement a service who manage this feature. Check this link: http://www.jiwhiz.com/post/2013/2/Add_RememberMe_Authentication_With_Spring_Security